# How to set variable to 0 where case has undefined gender

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having issues with determining gender in Rstudio, derived from a (first) name. I got the function to work, but not all cases in the df have first names from which gender can be derived by the gender() function.

I'm using the following code to derive gender from the first name column:

```
campaigns_tidy$creator_gender <- gender(campaigns_tidy$creator_firstname, method = c("ssa"))
```

This gives me the error :

> "replacement has 5852 rows, data has 6268"

How could I fill `campaigns_tidy$creator_gender` with e.g. "Unknown" for the cases where gender can't be derived from the name? I also tried creating a different `gender-df` and (left) merging this with the original df, but this results in an error that not all cases are unique.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you please provide a code example replicating the exact issue so that it would be easier to look and suggest

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and R, so I'm not sure what you're referring to. I hope this is what you asked for:
campaigns_tidy$creator_firstname <- sapply(strsplit(campaigns_tidy$creator, " "), '[', 1)
campaigns_tidy <- subset(campaigns_tidy, campaigns_tidy$creator_firstname != "Team")
campaigns_tidy$creator_gender <- (gender(campaigns_tidy$creator_firstname, method = c("ssa")))

Answer (score 0):

The `gender()` function (from gender package) returns a data frame but omits the rows with names which it does not recognise leading to the mismatch in rownumber.

A solution to your problem would be to write a function which takes in a single name and returns the gender if it is recognised and 'unknown' otherwise. 
A new column containing gender information can now be added to your original data by applying your new function to the column creator_name row by row (so the function is passed only one name at a time):

```
library(gender)
library(dplyr)

campaigns_tidy <- data.frame(creator_firstname = c("Peter","Hannah","Nonsense"), 
                             stringsAsFactors = F)

get_gender <- function(name) {
  gender_df <- gender(name, method = c("ssa"))
  ifelse(nrow(gender_df) == 1, gender_df$gender, "unknown")
}

campaigns_tidy %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(creator_gender = get_gender(creator_firstname))
```